# what is the format of stored and queried data using ARC2

Tags: php, rdf, sparql

I have to query RDF triples using SPARQL.
I started to use ARC2 to make this, but i have 2 problems:
1: To use ARC2, how can/must i store my RDF triples? just in RDF files or in MYsql database
Cause i found this example:

```
$query = '
      PREFIX rdf:      <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
      PREFIX rdfs:     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
      select distinct ?l ?c 
         where {?c a rdfs:Class. ?c rdfs:label ?l}
      limit 100
  ';
```

2: how to call my data in a query? what is the concretely signification of this URI:http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns# ? This is the URI of what? and how can i make an URI for my data?

Thank you

Comment: IN RDF, resources are **identified** by URIs.  Those don't need to be dereference-able;  they just need to be consistent. `PREFIX rdf:      <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>` means that in the rest  of the query, something like `rdfs:Class` is shorthand for  `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Class`.

Comment: Yes but my triples are local, they don't have URI? i just have rdf triples, how must i store them? just in an rdf file?

Comment: Where your data is *stored* doesn't have anything to do with the URIs used to identify resources.  E.g., I might have the triple `<http://stackoverflow.com/users/3132739/bignoob> <http://stackoverflow.com/asked> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/23642556/1281433>` to represent that you asked this question.  The URIs identify the things, not where data is stored.

Comment: ok i understand. Now i will make a lot of triples, later i will query them. So what do you think? is it better to use ARC2? or you think there is no need to arc2. Just i need to store my triples in rdf files and then i will query them using sparqlLib and php? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/28245/what-is-the-format-of-stored-and-queried-data-using-arc2

Comment: please answer me if you know the answer. I'm searching that during 6 months in Google without finding anything. Please.

Comment: I don't have any familiarity with ARC2.  If it processes RDF data though, I'd expect you should store it in RDF.  If it processes databases, I'd expect you store data in databases.  Searching for "arc2 php" on Google turned up https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki/Getting-started-with-ARC2, which  the second code shows how to load an RDF (ttl is the extension of a Turtle RDF file) document and access the triples.  That document is dated 2012, so I'm surprised it hasn't turned up in the last 6 months of querying. After, it says "Some components need a MySQL database (for example the…

Comment: … RDF store and the SPARQL engine)."  Sounds like if you want to use SPARQL, you'll need a database.  The section [A concrete example](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki/Getting-started-with-ARC2#a-complete-example) shows how to connect to a database and run a SPARQL query.  The documentation for a package is one of the places that you should be looking at for "research effort".

Comment: I have seen all that. The example does't work correctly.

Comment: Questions should *show* a fair amount of research effort;  if you've read that documentation, and its examples don't work, then you should mention that in the question.  Otherwise, well meaning people will start by pointing you there, or posting an answer that works through the example.  If the example in the documentation doesn't work, then you should probably contact the maintainer (how else will it get fixed?).  Additionally, it's a *much* better and more specific starting point for a question.  Post a question along the lines of "This example is in the documentation.  When I run it, I get…

Comment: …this unexpected behavior, or this error.  I thought I was following the example exactly.  What am I doing wrong?"  Then people have a starting point, and there's some clear *expected* output to aim for, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ARC2 is bundled with [mysql-based storage](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki/Using-ARC%27s-RDF-Store) and as long as your project is just an experiment it should work just fine

If you plan to use this for heavy processing then you should consider using [external triplestores](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki/Remote-Stores-and-Endpoints) such as [Virtuoso](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/) but in this case you might as well look into using [EasyRDF](http://www.easyrdf.org/) as your php-interface.

The good part is that no matter what kind of storage you use, most of the SPARQL-queries should be just the same. The [official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) is written in a very simple language and you should definitely read it.

Comment: thanks but this is not my question: "If i could use arc2 or no" My question was: how to store my data? in rdf files or in mysql database? if in rdf files, so i think that there is no need to arc2.